# Why GO panics with 'concurrent map writes' even with locks in place?

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, goroutine

When trying to use this struct with multiple goroutines sometimes I get one of these errors:

`fatal error: concurrent map read and map write`

or

`concurrent map writes`

After reading the [this thread](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20060) I made sure to return a reference in the constructor and pass in a reference to the receivers.

The entirety of the code where this is being used is in [this github repo](https://github.com/aldeano19/JuliusCaesar/blob/master/url-scraper.go)

```
type concurrentStorage struct {
    sync.Mutex
    domain string
    urls map[url.URL]bool
}

func newConcurrentStorage(d string) *concurrentStorage{
    return &concurrentStorage{
        domain: d,
        urls: map[url.URL]bool{},
    }
}

func (c *concurrentStorage) add(u url.URL) (bool) {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    if _, ok := c.urls[u]; ok{
        return false
    }
    c.urls[u] = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: You are only locking around writes, you need to lock around reads too.

Comment: Since you didn't include a corresponding read method, I assume you're reading from the `urls` map somewhere else in your package.

Comment: No read was being performed at this point. The struct was used to mimic a set basically to check if the URL had been seen before or not. The check happens with the add() function. Now I have added a size() function that does locks in order to get the size of the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon reading the code on Github that you linked to, the `crawl()` function accepts a `concurrentStorage` (not a pointer).

For each de-reference (ie: `*urlSet`) when calling `crawl()`, you are copying the `concurrentStorage` struct (including the `sync.Mutex`) while the map retains the pointer to the original. This means that your mutexes are isolated to each goroutine, while they are sharing the same state.

If you change `crawl()` to accept a pointer instead, and stop de-referencing `concurrentStorage`, it will work as you intend.